# how to use php add a class to the code?

Tags: php

```
<div class="centerBox">
<div class="centerBox line-y">
<div class="centerBox line_y">
<div class="centerBox">
<div class="centerBox line_y">
<div class="centerBox line_y">
<div class="centerBox">
<div class="centerBox line_y">
<div class="centerBox line_y">
```

I want to use  loop to add a class named `line_y` to the above code, how should i do? thank you.

add  `line-y` to 2,3,5,6,8,9 lines

Comment: Please concrete your question.

Comment: It's very hard to tell what you're question is. Could you add what the output should look like exactly? Also, note that HTML is _markup_ not _code_, it's a small but important distinction.

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop with a modulo division.

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
  if( ($i % 3) === 0 )
    echo '<div class="centerBox">';
  else
    echo '<div class="centerBox line_y">';
}
```

The if condition matches line 0, 3, 6 and so on (first line is line 0).

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you really want here. And how you are reading this chunk of HTML. Besides that the chunk of HTML code is not valid as displayed above. That being said.

You could just use a simple str_replace for this.

```
$str = '<div class="centerBox">
<div class="centerBox line-y">
<div class="centerBox line_y">
<div class="centerBox">
<div class="centerBox line_y">
<div class="centerBox line_y">
<div class="centerBox">
<div class="centerBox line_y">
<div class="centerBox line_y">';

echo str_replace('"centerBox"', '"centerBox line_y"', $str);
```